# Ember.js view not being autoupdated

Tags: javascript, ember.js, refresh, components

I'm stuck in the 'Scrumptious' bookmark app created in a Tuts+ Course called 'Let's Learn Ember'. As the course is some months old, I'm trying to re-do the app using the most updated versions of Ember.js and Ember-Data.

*Here's the repo*: https://github.com/jantequera/scrumptious

*NOTE*: due to @claptimes request, I've added a jsbin of the project: http://jsbin.com/ukuDORUZ/2/edit?html,js,console

The thing is, that in the 'bookmarks' template, when I add a new bookmark, it is stored and the "create Bookmark" partial disappears, but the bookmarks table isn't updated, and it doesn't even reflect the changes in the newly created bookmark on real-time, which is the intended behaviour. In other words, I have to refresh the browser in order to see the new bookmark in the table, which is not the way an ember.js app should work.

As I am learning Ember, I might have missed or misunderstood something in the guides that explains this, so any help is welcome. Below I expose the code, if you wish to see it in context or even try it out, use the repo above. Thanks!

**EDIT** Anton below pointed out and advised the usage of components, which make the jsfiddle above work. However, when I use this solution in my local copy, it wouldn't work **UNLESS** I use the FixtureAdapter INSTEAD of the LSAdapter (local-storage). Any clue?

Comment: any messages in console?

Comment: Try setting up a jsfiddle?

Comment: @claptimes: Sure, here you go! Note that I'm using the fixture adapter instead.

http://jsbin.com/ukuDORUZ/2/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @SteveH. : No messages at all, but on the jsfiddle linked above there's a strage loop (check console messages when adding a bookmark) that doesn't happen at all in local development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ukuDORUZ/6

You use "render" helper:

```
{{render "table" controller.regular}}
```

model is not updated in "table" template when you create new bookmark and update controller.regular

you can use component (http://emberjs.com/guides/components/) and bind your model to component's parameter:

```
{{bookmarks-table elementsBinding="controller.regular"}}
```

http://jsbin.com/ukuDORUZ/6

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would upvote it but I haven't got enough reputation!

I can't however mark it as an accepted answer because although it works in the jsfiddle it doesn't work in my local copy of the project UNLESS I change the localstorage-adapter usage for the Fixture adapter!

That's very strange! I'll edit the post to include the partial solution you provided!

Comment: just set model.favorite to false before save

Comment: your filters expect true or false but new record with LSAdapter contains undefined instead of false. model.set('favorite', false);